# Getting values from mysql tables

Tags: php, sql

I'm new at using sql but I have a problem that I just can't seem to solve. I have four tables: T_Item, t_trade, T_sender_trade and T_receiver_trade like this:

```
T_Item
(itemID, name, category, description, description);

T_Trade
(tradeID, date, senderID, receiverID);

T_sender_trade
(tradeID, senderItemID) - both foreign keys from the previous tables

T_receiver_trade
(tradeID, receiverItemID) - as in T_sender_trade
```

It is meant that a sender and a receiver trade two items. What I want to do is create a table in html with php, with the following information:

- description of the item from the sender
- description of the item from the receiver
- date (trade's date)

I'm using a Class Trade as it is requires by my teacher.
I used the following code in the class:

```
<?php
    require_once '../utils/ligabd.php'; (uses the connection to the mysql in another class)

Class Trade
    {
            public $tradeID;
        public $date;
        public $senderID;
        public $receiverID


        public function __construct($date = null, $senderID= null, $receiverID=null) {

            $this->date= $date;
                $this->senderID= $senderID;
            $this->receiverID= $receiverID;     
                                }

    public static function load($tradeID) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM T_Trade");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Troca não existente ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row) {
      $t = new Trade();
      $t->tradeID = $row["tradeID"];
      $t->date = $row["date"];
      $t->senderID=$row["senderID"];
      $t->receiverID=$row["receiverID"];
      return $t;
    } else {
      return NULL;
    }
    }

public static function returnsSenderItem($tradeID) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM T_Item, T_sender_trade where T_sender_trade.tradeID= $tradeID AND T_sender_trade.senderItemID =T_Item.ItemID");

if(!$result) {
die ('Trade not found ' .mysql_error());
}
$rows=Array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
            }
            return $rows;
            }
```

And the same for the receiver's Item.
In the php code i use (just to get one item's description because I was able to get the ttade's date):

```
include '../classes/troca.php';
$tradeID=$_GET[tradeID];
$trade=Trade::load($tradeID);
echo $trade->date; 
$sender=Trade::returnsSenderItem($tradeID);
foreach($senderr as $s):
echo $s['name'];
endforeach;
```

And I am supposed to use a code like this to make my table. The thing is the program isn't able to find the data from T_Item.. what should I change in my class/php so it does?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the descriptions of both the sender and receiver's items, you will need to link to the T_Item table *twice* (once for each item) - this will require using table aliases, like so:

```
select t.tradeID,
       t.`date`,
       t.senderID,
       s.SenderItemID,
       si.description as SenderDescription,
       t.receiverID,
       r.ReceiverItemID,
       ri.description as ReceiverDescription
from T_Trade as t
join T_sender_trade as s on t.tradeID = s.tradeID
join T_Item as si on s.senderItemID = si.itemID
join T_receiver_trade as r on t.tradeID = r.tradeID
join T_Item as ri on s.receiverItemID = ri.itemID
where t.tradeID = $tradeID
```